# Setting up CredSSP properly for powershell multi-hop issue

Tags: powershell

I've encountering the double-hop issue with a script I'm writing. Issue right now is that when I get to `New-PSSession` on the computer remoting in. I get the following error:

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnoYo.png) if its too hard to read

[image]

Here's the code that runs on the original server:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\admin",     $CApassword)
$sesh = new-pssession -computername "MSSCA" -credential $CAcred -Authentication CredSSP
```

This `$sesh` variable comes back null and throws the error above.

Server executing powershell script/remoting is set to delegate fresh credentials to mssca (I DID specify the FQDN for this target server), and likewise mssca is set to receive.

I followed the instructions of the error message to modify the group policy, enabling `Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials` under `Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation -> Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials` which was already set up to delegate fresh credentials to `mssca`.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Just a side note, powershell allows you to copy text to clipboard. You can use that instead of the image. +1 for the question btw.

Comment: @Neolisk Cool, thanks. I'm exploring the group policy stuff mentioned in the error message but no luck yet.

Comment: Did you enable CredSSP on both ends? See http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx, especially the parts about `Enable-WSManCredSSP`

Comment: @alroc Yes, please read 3rd to last paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Though the error message said to use the FQDN, my script was not using the FQDN. After using the "NTLM-only server authentication" option instead as well as changing the the group policy setting to just `mssca` and NOT the FQDN, it worked.