# Cannot find path 'SharePath' because it does not exist

Tags: powershell

I am running command to copy a file from shared location to the local machine.

Command is `Copy-Item '\\ServerName\share\Setup\Setup.msi' 'C:\Windows\Temp\RiversandSetup'`
This command is works fine when I run it from Server1. But when i run same command from remote machine by opening a session it fails with error 'Cannot find path 'SharePath' because it does not exist.'. Command is `$sessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName RemoteServerName
Invoke-Command -session $sessions -ScriptBlock {Copy-Item '\\SharePath\share\Setup\Setup.msi' 'C:\Windows\Temp\RiversandSetup'}`

Please advice.

Comment: Check the security on the share to ensure that a low-privileged user will have rights to it.  If it is more highly secured, then add a Credential object to your session.

Comment: You have two different pahts: `\\Servername...` and `\\SharePath...`. Double-check the paths, as subtle changes in names often indicate typos. Does the 1st command work if you log on locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely running into an issue with double-hop authentication. This could help but it depends on your environment:

[Setting up CredSSP properly for powershell multi-hop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365739/setting-up-credssp-properly-for-powershell-multi-hop-issue)