# Get IIS Bindings from many webservers using powershell remoting, invoke command and module webadministration

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Right now I made a small script to see my actual webbindings on a server.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration;

$today = Get-Date -format M.d.yyyy
$machine = hostname
function IISRport

{
Get-ChildItem -path IIS:\Sites | out-file "\\server01\d$\_utils\PowerShell Scripts\IISexport\IISExport$machine$today.txt"
}

IISReport
```

This wil outfile my IIS bindings to txt which works brilliant.
I now need to invoke that command to several other servers and save the output file on one server. since the machine name will be diffrent I expect as many outputs as servers.

I tried for example the following :

```
icm -comp server02 {get-childitem -path IIS:\Sites}
```

But than the imported Module webadministration is not working, since I only loaded on one server. So I tried to load that remotely using :

```
icm -comp server02 {import-module webadministration}
```

without success.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the data from all machines defined in `$machines` and output to *\\server01\d$_utils\PowerShell Scripts\IISexport\*.

```powershell
$today = Get-Date -format M.d.yyyy
$machines = @("server01","server02")
foreach($machine in $machines) {
    icm -comp $machine { param($machine,$today)
        import-module webadministration;
        Get-ChildItem -path IIS:\Sites | 
        out-file "\\server01\d$\_utils\PowerShell Scripts\IISexport\IISExport$machine$today.txt"
    } -ArgumentList $machine,$today 
}
```

You can of course change the output path( and import list of machines from a file,AD or some other source).

Comment: thanks, seems to be exactly what I needed. Interesting that I get an error "access denied" OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException   - even though i am domain admin. hmm

Comment: That's a double hop authentication issue, you can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752707/cannot-find-path-sharepath-because-it-does-not-exist/21757438).. Best thing you can do is to dump the report to the same location on all boxes and pull them all at the end.

Comment: yes thats what i thought about. I guess that's what I do... thanks